# Having trouble with syntax for populating listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner programmer and am making VBA macro for my senior capstone project.  I'm trying to populate a listbox with the data in "A column".  It must be dynamic, because the user will edit the data.  I know its simple for a seasoned coder, but I'm having problems with the syntax.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastRowControllers, LastRowBrakes As Integer
Dim Brakes, Controllers As Range

With Worksheets("ControllersInventory")
LastRowControllers = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("BrakesInventory")
LastRowBrakes = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set Controllers = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowControllers, 1))
Set Brakes = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowBrakes, 1))

'Populate Controller_List
Worksheets("ControllerInventory").Select
With Controller_List
.RowSource "= Controllers"
End With

'Populate Brake_List
Worksheets("BrakeInventory").Select

With Brake_List
   .RowSource "= Brakes"
End With
End Sub
```

I found an alternative way for populating listboxes, however my syntax is wrong and I would like to use proper coding techniques by using declared ranges.

```
Brake_List.RowSource = Worksheets("BrakeInventory").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowControllers, 1)).Address
```

Comment: Try changing `.address` to `.value`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
ListBox1.List = Rng.Value
```

Comment: @ Patrick Lepelletier- How do you figure the range is not dynamic?

Comment: `listbox1.list` fills it the same way it would fill an array, to make it dynamic use `listbox1.rowsource`.  Before more questions, open VBE and try...

Answer (score 0):

Dispense with the `.Select` it doesn't buy you anything

`.RowSource` is expecting a range. You're trying to assign it a string value (denoted by the ""), but you're not getting that far because the `=` sign is in the quotes.

```
With Controller_List
  .RowSource = Controllers
End With

'Populate Brake_List
With Brake_List
 .RowSource = Brakes
End With
```

Comment: this throws a type mistmatch error,and would anyway only work for ranges in the activesheet, you need to reference sheets ! (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I see you often forget to reference the worksheet when using `Range` or `Cells`.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'first error when declaring variables, you declared some as variant
Dim LastRowControllers as Long, LastRowBrakes As Long 'rows can go more than 65535 (integer limit) , so i use Long
Dim Brakes as Range, Controllers As Range

With Worksheets("ControllersInventory")
    LastRowControllers = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Controllers = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRowControllers, 1))
End With

With Worksheets("BrakesInventory")
    LastRowBrakes = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Brakes = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRowBrakes, 1))
End With

'Populate Controller_List

With Controller_List
    '.List= Controllers.value 'works but not dynamic
    .Rowsource = Controllers.Parent.Name & "!" & Controllers.Address
End With

'Populate Brake_List
With Brake_List
   '.List = Brakes.value 'works but not dynamic
   .Rowsource = Brakes.Parent.Name & "!" & Brakes.Address ' example  = "Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10"
End With

Set Brakes = Nothing
Set Controllers = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also note, if the data needs to be dynamic, i think the userform must be called this way:

```
Userform1.Show False
```